# Copying from the start of one iterator to the end of another objects iterator

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

This puzzling code was found in my application where I had written an std::copy with an iterator of one array for the first parameter, and then mistakenly used the end iterator of another array for the second parameter. When looking at this code I would have imagined that either nothing would have happened, or the code would have blown up entirely. However this piece of code has been working correctly for months, always producing the same result.

```
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::array;
using std::printf;

int main()
{
    array<int,5> a = {0,1,2,3,4};
    array<int,5> b = {5,6,7,8,9};

    array<int,5> c;
    std::fill(c.begin(), c.end(), 0);

    std::copy(b.begin(), a.end(), c.begin());
    for(int element : c)
        printf("%d", element);
}
```

If you run this code [here](https://tio.run/##lY7LDoIwEEXXna9oMCYlGYkvfIDyJW7KULAJFoK6MMZvx7bGR3TlZh733skZattRRdQPtKH6XCi@kV0nLxm8heOp0E20zwDOR20qbvck8an0U2k7bU5l2tvKD1IbEcIVmM9trIZxxiXf8usYJzjFGc5v6ZedOzvGBS5xhesfm1IAYJ5V6roWFOWqchzkFClTuGEc2hArm064N1StDsr2hFMIjD0@FMGwCPDp2fxL35nAn3sENe1F5G@EfCJeWHf6H@nW93c) you will see that the output is `56789`, the contents of the array b. I am wondering why this is the case.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Since it is undefined behaviour anything can happen, it can even look like it works.

Comment: Perhaps at some point it happens to hit the end of the a array so stops, up to that point its been merrily copying past the end of your b array which just happens not to have had any noticeable effect.

Comment: It is UB, but in your case, in memory you have `c, b, a` (reverse order with stack), so it happens you copy 10 elements from `b` (5,6,7,8,9, 0,1,2,3,4) to `c`, overwriting b with `0,1,2,3,4`.

Comment: It fails here: https://ideone.com/bSqNEw You were unlucky, all those months, when it "worked".

Comment: Many c++ errors cause undefined behavior and are not required to be detected by the compiler. Unfortunately, in c++, successfully compiling code, running it and obtaining the expected result is not enough to prove that your code is legal. Undefined behavior may appear to work for some time and suddenly change unexpectedly.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right, when after the std::copy the contents of A and B are identical. Thanks!